# Typescript object key type as a subset of the keys of a generic type

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

How do I create an object with keys as a subset of the keys of a generic type?

I need a type for the headers parameter that will be a subset of the keys of 'T' that maps to a string value.

```js
export abstract class Table<T> {
  constructor(
    protected data: T[],
    //this requires the headers object to contain all the keys in T
    protected headers: { [key in keyof T]: string },

    //but I need something like this
    protected headers: { [keyof T]: string }
  ) {}
  //...abstract methods
}

//example
interface User {
  username: string;
  password: string;
  age: number;
}

class UserTable extends Table<User> {
  constructor(data: User[]) {

    //this does not compile since it does not contain all the keys from User
    super(data, {
      username: 'User',
      age: 'Age',
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) to create a type with the same keys as `T` but of `string` type and [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) to make the keys optional:

```
export abstract class Table<T> {
  constructor(
    protected data: T[],
    //this requires the headers object to contain all the keys in T
    protected headers: Partial<Record<keyof T, string>>,
  ) {}
  //...abstract methods
}

//example
interface User {
  username: string;
  password: string;
  age: number;
}

class UserTable extends Table<User> {
  constructor(data: User[]) {

    //this does not compile since it does not contain all the keys from User
    super(data, {
      username: 'User',
      age: 'Age',
    });
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)